# Would naming a bill payment app "Bill Nigh" be considered unlawful use of someone's name or likeness?

Tags: trademark, name

I thought "Bill Nigh" would be a punny name for a bill payment/management app. Would such a name be considered unlawful use of someone's name or likeness? Not thinking of anyone specifically.

Comment: `+1` I guess if one of them sued you you could say you were thinking about the other one, but that runs out pretty quickly